# TranslateTo animation in xamarin. Forms grid view

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im working ok a LUDO app as my xamarin practice. I have a LUDO board designed with grid views and each cell is a stack layout with row and a column. I want to move my coins from one cell to amother when the dice is thrown. As per the number comes on dice. For now Im just adding the coin as a child to the stack layout, but I want to move it from one cell to another. For that I'm thinking of translateto animation, but how to use translateto animation in a grid cells. Or is there any other way to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: Think of your grid cells only as coords providers. You can move your coin inside a table C everywhere, the table A containing your table B with ludo table and table C overlaying it.

Comment: Hi @NickKovalsky could you please explain it in XAML structure as table A, B and C.

Comment: <!--main container-->
        <Grid StyleId="TableA" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Grid StyleId="TableB" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <!--playground-->
            </Grid>

            <Grid StyleId="TableC" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <!--overlay with coins-->
            </Grid>

        </Grid>

Comment: Thanks @nick i already have my table c as a grid layout and table c contains multiple cells (stacklayout) with different row number and column number. But my question is how to translate a coin from one cell to another. Right now I'm just adding a coin to the cell as a child, when dice is thrown.

Comment: http://jmillerdev.net/skype-style-animations-with-xamarin-forms/